# Can you summon a blind mob in minecraft 1.16

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to attempt to fight a zombie that has 84 health and can do 31 damage, just like the warden that will be added in Minecraft 1.17. I know how you can make custom health and damage values, but I do not know how to summon a blind mob. Is it possible to summon a blind mob? Also, give me the exact command to do it if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just throw a splash potion of blindness at him, or execute the command
/effect give @e [name=*the name of your creature so zombie*] minecraft:blindness 1000000 1 true
1000000 is I believe, the longest amount of seconds you can /give an effect, 1 will make him be able to see only the two or three blocks in front of him, and true is simply so you do not see the particles. You could just decide to erase the true and then the particles would be visible, but you can still turn them down in your visibility settings. Is this for Java, bedrock? And survival or creative? It might be possible in survival, but it would either be extremely hard, or impossible...

Comment: This is for bedrock.

Comment: Also if another zombie had spawned naturally they would become blind, too.

Comment: And I will summon in creative but fight in survival

Comment: What about making it 4 blocks tall? I want that, too.

Comment: And also it would still see you when you were like a couple blocks away.